# Autoresize does not work during add subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view with a button. when i click on the button i am adding another view to the current view using addSubView. In iPhone it works fine. but in iPad autoresize does not work for the subview that i added. I have set autoresize properly in Inspector. but still does not work. Any ideas?

I guess autoresize does not work when using [self.view addSubview : newView];

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try calling 
[viewContainer setNeedsLayout];
this should do the job

and watch this.. really helped me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129013